Taking screenshot of area selected on Google Maps and saving it to upload file in Flask
I want to take a screenshot from selected area and save static/uploads folder under the python/flask project using Google Maps APİ.
How can I do it?
my html code:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Polygon Arrays</title>
    <style>
        /* Set the size of the map and side panel */
        #map {
            height: 100%;
            width: 70%;
            float: left;
        }

        #panel {
            width: 30%;
            height: 100%;
            float: right;
            overflow: auto; /* Enable scrolling if content overflows */
        }

        /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
        html,
        body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="panel">
        <h2>Areas</h2>
        <p id="coordinates"></p>
        <button id="sendButton">Send</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        let map;
        let infoWindow;

        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
                zoom: 5,
                center: { lat: 24.886, lng: -70.268 },
                mapTypeId: "terrain",
            });

            infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

            const drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
                drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
                drawingControl: true,
                drawingControlOptions: {
                    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
                    drawingModes: ['polygon']
                }
            });

            drawingManager.setMap(map);

            google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
                if (event.type === google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON) {
                    const polygon = event.overlay;
                    const coordinates = polygon.getPath().getArray();
                    showArrays(coordinates);

                    google.maps.event.addListener(polygon, 'click', function(event) {
                        showClickCoordinate(event);
                    });

                    document.getElementById('sendButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
                        captureAndSendImage(polygon);
                    });
                }
            });
        }

      

        
        function captureAndSendImage(polygon) {
            const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            const path = polygon.getPath();
            path.forEach(function (point) {
                bounds.extend(point);
            });
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
            setTimeout(() => {
                html2canvas(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    useCORS: true,
                    allowTaint: true,
                    logging: true
                }).then(canvas => {
                    const imageData = canvas.toDataURL();
                    sendImageToFlask(imageData);
                });
            }, 500);
        }

        function sendImageToFlask(imageData) {
            fetch('/upload_image', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ 'imageData': imageData }),
            })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('Flask response:', data);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error:', error);
            });
        }

        window.initMap = initMap;
    </script>

    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API&libraries=drawing&callback=initMap&v=weekly" defer></script>
    <script src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

my flask/python code:

from flask import Flask, render_template, request, jsonify
import base64

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('4.html')

@app.route('/upload_image', methods=['POST'])
def upload_image():
    data = request.get_json()
    encoded_image = data['imageData'].split(",")[1]  

    image_bytes = base64.b64decode(encoded_image)

    with open('static/uploads/c.png', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(image_bytes)

    return jsonify({'message': 'Image uploaded successfully'})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)

